# ReactJS chrome extension installed but not showing up

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, reactjs

Anyone know why the ReactJS Chrome browser extension isn't showing for mein dev tools? It's installed, at one point it was working.

I'm using chrome Version 39.0.2171.65 (64-bit) on Mac OS X v 10.7.5

I read the reviews on this extension, some people said need to expose React as a global. I'm using React NPM with:
`var React = require('react');`

Comment: you should set `window.React`, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347489/react-dev-tools-not-loading-in-chrome-browser

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In `chrome://extensions/` select `Allow access to file URLs` for the `React Developer Tools` extension, using v0.13.1 of React. I didn't need to add anything to my source code.

Comment: Check for  ⚛️ Components tab and  ⚛️ Profiler tab in newer version. Facebook have updated React DevTools to have Components and Profiler Tabs it serves same purpose as React tab in older versions.

Comment: @Shailesh you should write this as an answer.

Comment: To reach the `Allow access to file URLs` selector menu, click on the `details` button in the bottom left corner of your extension card.

Answer (score 118):

I was having this issue just now and to solve it I had to open dev tools -> click the gear icon on the top right of the dev tools window then in the far right column at the very bottom is a button that should say "restore defaults and reload" click that. I was not able to figure out the exact reason it was not appearing but it at least gets react debugging working again.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me after trying everything else. Thanks.

Comment: When all fails, 5 years after the question was posted, there comes a stack-overflow hero. I'd give 5 upvotes if possible.

Comment: Has anyone gone down the rabbit hole to identify that single setting that messed up the extension?

Comment: Not a clue as for the cause - this happened to me on a mostly fresh Vivaldi install.

Answer (score 38):

Just happened to me on Chrome 100. Reloading the page, reopening DevTools panel, toggling the extension on/off, restarting the browser and closing other app windows didn't help.

What fixed it for me was:
`CMD+SHIFT+P` and selecting "Reload DevTools" from the command panel.
For non-Macs it will probably be `CTRL+SHIFT+P`.

Comment: helped me in chrome Version 103.0 as well. Thanks!

Comment: worked on chrome version Version 114.0.5735.248 . thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for our team. The above solutions, although got more upvotes, but did not work.

Comment: Simply closing and reopening dev tools did it for me

Answer (score 14):

React extension shows up only when you have react loaded into the browser in global scope. Like @nlgndg mentions it should be present as window.React

Comment: Copy Paste from other answer: The main requirement is that window.React is set. If you're using a module system (as I am using Browserify):
`typeof window !== "undefined" && (window.React = React)`
This should usually be done in your main source file.

Comment: I have given him due credit for the answer, just thought it's better served as an answer for everyone to see than a comment.

Comment: Thanks , just typed  window.React = {} in the console and the React tab became visible in the chrome dev tools besides the audits tab .

Answer (score 6):

**Restarting Chrome after installation** seems to help, apart from the other answers.

I couldn't find any info on that step in the Chrome Web Store or when clicking on the plugin, so just leaving it here.

Answer (score 4):

**TWO SIMPLE STEPS**

**1**. in **devTools** (inspect of page) press **ALT + R**

it will fix the problem
if did not

**2**. **Allow access to file URLs** to React Developer Tools

***STEPS :***

a. Extensions

b. React Developer Tools (**details btn**)

c. Check Allow access to file URLs

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-devtools/README.md#the-react-tab-shows-no-components

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem, I tried uninstalling the extension, activating and deactivating the URL file issue and it didn't work. What worked for me was: Go to Applications -> Service Workers and uncheck all checkboxes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I was using http://localhost:3000, I went to extensions and reset the settings like toggle them and it started showing components and profiler tabs for me.. I dont know thats a solution, but it worked for me..
PS Also updated chrome version too.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, I tried re-installing the extension, the solution with `CMD+SHIFT+P`, clicking gear icon then "restore default and load", still it did not work.

I don't know if this is what fixed it but I changed the dock side from right to bottom and reloaded the page and I could see the "⚛️ Components" tab after that.

Answer (score 0):

In case none of the answers helped, try to open the extension's settings and check the option `Site access`. The value should be `on all sites`.
In case of `on click` or `on specific sites` the tabs won't showing up

Answer (score 0):

Recently, ReactJS stopped working in my browser. The problem was that one of my extensions got updated and was interfering with the other one. If you have this problem, try disabling all extensions except the one you need.

Answer (score -2):

i had the same problem . and it was solved just like @Siddharth Sharma said . open the console and create a react object just like bellow .

```
window.react = {};
```