# Debugging a React App, with Chrome extension "React Developer Tools 4.10.1" I'm expecting to see a React Tab

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

From this tutorial, I see a React tab in dev tools to help debug. But not getting it on my own. I have Chrome extension "React Developer Tools 4.10.1". What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: It’s called “Components” now. Otherwise see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27030937/4722345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now there is two tabs in React Dev Tools: Components and Profiler.

[image]

Components expectedly display the structure of your components. Probably it`s what you are looking for.

[image]

Profiler let`s you to take records during debugging of application and see useful diagnostic information.

[image]

Comment: I've been using composer and it is helpful. Just looking at the debugging trace from the tutorial I have pictured above, being able to debug trace the rendered code seems really useful. I wish that was available.

Comment: @Bill have you tried clicking the cursor icon on the top left (2nd from the top)? I’m assuming that’s what you’re looking for