# How to see React tab in Chrome devtools when debugging React-Native app?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, react-native

Can't see the `React` tab in Chrome dev tools when debugging my react-native app on android, real device.

I followed the instructions here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

- I have the **React dev tools extension** installed and up-to-date (0.14.8).
- My **Chrome browser** is also currently up-to-date (Version 48.0.2564.109 m).
- I also made sure to run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`.
- These are my **React related dependencies** in my `package.json`:

  `"react": "^0.14.5",
  "react-native": "0.19.0",
  "react-native-htmlview": "0.2.0",
  "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "0.3.5",
  "react-native-scrollview-lazyload": "1.0.4",
  "react-native-swiper": "1.4.3",
  "react-native-viewport-units": "0.0.5",
  "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
  "redux": "3.3.1",
  "redux-thunk": "1.0.3"`
- I tried the suggestion in this SO question too: [react dev tools not loading in Chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347489/react-dev-tools-not-loading-in-chrome-browser) - didn't help

How can I get the tab to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dev tools are not working currently as explained [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#content).

It looks like developers are working on it.