# Is it possible to use react locally without web-access and without a server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to use react locally without web-access and without a server?

For other HTML/css/script stuff it is possible to just browse a file using an URL like "file:///myFile.html". I have seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/30270618/4142984 but, firstly I don't use chrome and secondly I don't want to be seen on the net every time I do a little testing. (And, yes, I'm not just a *little* paranoid.)

So I've downloaded the js-files and replaced

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

with

```
<script src="react-development.js" ></script>
<script src="react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

and I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: React is undefined

Adding the code suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26347762/4142984 I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

Is there a way to fix it, and if so, how?

---

One reason behind this question is that I don't trust the cloud: one hack to the server or one man(m/w/x)-in-the-middle attack and everything based on it will fail (best case) or do real damage.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)? You can make your app and run a server on localhost.

Comment: @SumitChaturvedi Yes, but I would like to run without a server (browser only), ***and*** it gets me into version hell: "You are running Node 8.10.0.
Create React App requires Node 10 or higher. 
Please update your version of Node.
" And I already did 3 to 5 updates like that.

Comment: did you even check your network tab if the js-ressources were even found and loaded? relative uris are always sketchy and I assume thats your issue

Comment: okay, to take your paranoia, running a local webserver is exactly as secure as your machine is anyways. Because the only way to get hacked is your machine is hacked and not the running server-software, maybe you should go with simple apache/mysql than running node

Comment: @johnSmith that much, that well, but code-run-debug-(drink) cycles are much shorter without a server.

Comment: @johnSmith this is going to be a chat. I've never created on. Can you open one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224101/discussion-between-john-smith-and-gyro-gearloose).

Answer (score 1):

Better off using a different language or creating your own javascript framework.

Here's an example on how to build your own framework
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-i-wrote-javascript-framework-59b40dca3366?gi=208530978b11

Comment: "Better off using a different language or creating your own javascript framework." ... You made my day! ... Unfortunately, customers employing freelancers have there own opinions on what to use.

Comment: I frequently actually **did** make my own frameworks from scratch; solid, efficient and focused.